# How to synchronize textarea containing json and text fields linked to a specific json property

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm experimenting with ember.js. My goal is to have a textarea containing some json and some text fields close to it which contain the value of some specific property of the json. Let's say this is the json:

```
{
  property1 : "value1",
  property2 : "value2"
}
```

The first text field would be connected to property1 and the second to property2. Whenever I type something on one of the text field I want to keep the textarea up to date with the new json. Whenever I update the json from the textarea I want to keep the text fields up to date as well, as long as the json is still valid.

I got it working using a model that contains the json itself and a computed property which is used to get the json as string in order to show it on the text area, as well as to parse the json from the textarea in order to update the model.

```
App.JsonModel = Ember.Object.extend({
    json : {property1:"value1",property2:"value2"},
    asString : function(key, value) {
        //getter
        if (arguments.length === 1) {
            return JSON.stringify(this.get('json'), null, '  ');
        //setter
        } else {
            try {
                this.set('json', JSON.parse(value));
            } catch(err) {

            }    
            return value;
        }
    }.property('json', 'json.property1', 'json.property2')
});
```

And this is the html with the views:

```
json:
{{view Ember.TextArea valueBinding="App.jsonModel.asString" class="json"}}
property1:
{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="App.jsonModel.json.property1"}}
property2:
{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="App.jsonModel.json.property2"}}
```

You can have a look at the [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/javanna/9P9KD/1/) too.

There are a couple of things that I don't like in my current code:

- I need to specify all the properties that can cause a change in the version string of the json, since json itself is not enough, not sure if that is the expected behaviour: `.property('json', 'json.property1', 'json.property2')`. I would like to make the asString function as generic as possible, without mentioning any specific json property.
- The computed property getter and setter based on the `if (arguments.length === 1)` isn't that nice to read in my opinion.

Are there any other (hopefully better) ways to achieve the same goal with ember.js? How can I improve what I don't like here?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a complete answer for you. I do have a few bits and pieces that may prove useful though.

Get the property keys for any object, including an anonymous json object:

```
Ember.keys(someObject);
```

Set any random properties on an object from json:

```
someObject.setProperties({json:"data"});
```

There is also the companion getter:

```
someObject.getProperties("key1", "key2");
someObject.getProperties(Ember.keys(someObject));
```

Listing the keys is pretty useful in your case for tidying up the view and eaching your way through every property in a dynamically changing dataset.

I have not been able to make use of Ember.keys() to dynamically list properties to observe. I fear you have to make your simple json property into a more intelligent Ember object and set up observer on some "fake" property on it by implementing "propertyDidChange" or something.

Using setProperties will allow you to have the "json" as an Ember.Object and still set any dynamic property. The observing of "any" property of an object is the hard part. I am too new to Ember to have figured out a clean way of doing that... without a mess of observer stuff.